# Can I get the html dom val when I using dot.js temple?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dot.js

Now I am using dot.js ,in the web page,I have a span call 'spanHelloword' and its value is "helloworld".I want to get the span value in dot temple,How to do that?

```
<script id="j-tmpl" type="text/template">
{{ if(it.success && $('#spanHelloword').text()=='helloword'){ }}
<h2>results:</h2>
<ul>
    {{ for (var i = 0, l = it.data.length; i < l; i++) { }}
        <li>
            <h5>{{=it.data[i].title}}</h5>
            <p>{{!it.data[i].message}}</p>
        </li>
    {{ } }}
<ul>
 {{ }else{ }}
<h2>no data</h2>
 {{ } }}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>doT.js example</title>
    <script src="/application/html/js/olado/doT/doT.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="results"></div>
        <script>
            var tempFn = doT.template("{{~it.people :value:index}}<li>{{=value.firstName}} {{=value.lastName}}</li>{{~}}");
            var dat = {
                'people': [
               { 'firstName': 'Clark', 'lastName': 'Kent' },
               { 'firstName': 'Bruce', 'lastName': 'Wayne' },
               { 'firstName': 'Peter', 'lastName': 'Parker' }
                ]
            }
            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = tempFn(dat);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[click here](http://www.javascriptoo.com/dot-js)

Comment: I want to get the value in the script temple.It seem not what I want.